# Using instagram filters from an open source library

Tags: iphone, ios, image-processing

GPUIMage helped alot but exact result like instagram is not there. Found a new library but Not able to figure out how to use this. Any suggestions ?

https://github.com/binhdna/Instagram-Filters

Comment: "InstaFilters does talk to the GPU, but not in a direct way. It is built upon GPUImage" - If you understand how to use GPUImage, this simply builds on that with custom filter implementations. I'd be cautious, though, because the shader code and color maps appear to be ripped out of Instagram, so there may be copyright issues in using it.

Answer (score 1):

Check this git.. code is provided..so this will help you the most..

https://github.com/OmidH/Filtrr

Hope it Help to you :)